# Modelica Evaluate=true

Tags: modelica, dymola, evaluate

From the Modelica documentation, it seems annotation Evaluate only has an effect on parameters:
https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.Annotations.Evaluate.html

Using the Dymola variable editor, I can conveniently set the annotation on any variable/instance, see screenshot below. Does this have any effect or is the annotation just ignored?
If applied to the instance of a class, will the parameters in that class be evaluated, to the value set by the modifier (in the example screenshot, e.g. parameter yMax)?

[image: Dymola screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters of the class will be evaluated, https://specification.modelica.org/master/annotations.html#modelica:Evaluate

This was added in Modelica 3.5 (and supported earlier in Dymola with some minor differences that don't appear if you only use `Evaluate=true` - see https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/pull/2771 for details).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So Evaluate=true on instances of a class means: all parameters in that class are evaluated, and have the value as set by the modifier.

Comment: Follow-up question: Using the variable editor, I can also set Evaluate=true on any variable, like any Real or Integer. Does this have any effect at all?

Comment: For a non-parameter Integer or Real: No.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Then maybe the variable editor could be enhanced to not offer this for non-parameter variables. Or maybe check or translate could report a warning that it is ignored.